# Images in src tags not rendering in PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

I have a bunch of `img` tags with content inside their `src` attributes, however the images are not appearing when the application is loaded in PhoneGap. The images display/are visible fine in browser, however.

I have added the following to my `config.xml` file as per the documentation, as I suspected it was a whitelisting issue, however it didn't solve the issue.

```
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<access origin="*" />
```

Below is my `config.xml`

```html
<widget xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" id="com.private.private" version="0.0.3">
  <name>private</name>
  <description>private</description>
  <author href="http://private.co.nz" email="contact@private.co.nz">private</author>
  <content src="index.html"/>

  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" />
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1"/>
  
  <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>
  <preference name="orientation" value="default"/>
  <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
  <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
  <preference name="webviewbounce" value="true"/>
  <preference name="prerendered-icon" value="true"/>
  <preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false"/>
  <preference name="ios-statusbarstyle" value="black-opaque"/>
  <preference name="detect-data-types" value="true"/>
  <preference name="exit-on-suspend" value="false"/>
  <preference name="show-splash-screen-spinner" value="true"/>
  <preference name="auto-hide-splash-screen" value="true"/>
  <preference name="disable-cursor" value="false"/>
  <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14"/>
  <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
  
  <icon src="icon.png"/>
  <icon src="www/assets/images/icon.png" gap:platform="android"/>
  <icon src="www/assets/images/icon.png" gap:platform="ios"/>
  
  <gap:splash src="www/assets/images/splash.png" gap:platform="android" />
  <gap:splash src="www/assets/images/splash.png" gap:platform="ios" />
  
  <allow-navigation href="*" />
  <access origin="*" />
  
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*"/>
  <allow-intent href="tel:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="sms:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*"/>
  <allow-intent href="geo:*"/>

</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a blank index file with the images put in tags and they work fine with the posted configuration.

I am developing the original project using Angular2, perhaps there's something more going on that relates to the framework.

This means that the issue is not PhoneGap but is Angular2. In this case I have investigated further and asked a new question with a more suited description.

Comment: Just implied that the issue is the result of a different problem - you can follow the updated question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40858034/images-do-not-display-when-using-adobe-phonegap-angular2-pictures-src

Answer (score 0):

where does your images (the path in src) are found?
i had a similar problem and i fixed it by moving all of my images to the root folder (www) the same dir as my index.html,
as far as I know this a known bug with phonegap.

if it is the case and you try this, dont forget to change the src accordingly .

good luck!