# Images do not display when using Adobe PhoneGap + Angular2 (pictures & src)

Tags: cordova, angular, phonegap-build

I have created a brand new project using the cli.

I have tried adding a few image tags, each with a different kind of source. (local image, image from the web, image via https source)

On the browser, this renders all of them just fine, however when the project is built using Adobe PhoneGap (via the PhoneGap Desktop debugger + companion app), the images do not display.

The same project made purely in html (an index.html file with only one img tag) also works just fine

The inspector shows that the images are in their containers, with the correct links, however nothing appears on the screen.

I have tried using both

```
ng build --prod
ng build --prod --aot
```

In both cases, no change.

Project src: http://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3Fuz1vCRaY_T2hVeDJQcEswVGc

I'm using: http://docs.phonegap.com/references/desktop-app/

And : http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.adobe.phonegap.app&hl=en

---

**Bonus Images:**

The phone displays the site being rendered in PhoneGap using the developer app above. The computer screen displays the same page being loaded in browser.

When all I have is an image tag:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHolh.jpg

When the image tag is inside an angular project, placed in the main component's template (app.component) then built with --prod --aot
https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfCf4.jpg

Comment: I solved the issue "in the short term" by converting the images to base64, which phonegap seems to be able to render.

to do that, in my component, I have a `<canvas>` and an `<img>`. The `<canvas>` is hidden and is only used so I can call it's .toDataURL() method. I take the return value store it as a variable which I `[src]="bind"` to the `img` tag.

I guess I could use the `canvas` to begin with, the `img` seems redundant now, but I don't want to change it.